# Trying to show $\mathrm{End}_R(S^n) \cong M_n(\mathrm{End}_R(S))$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory

Trying to show $\mathrm{End}_R(S^n) \cong M_n(\mathrm{End}_R(S))$ where $S$ is simple $R$-module.

I'm using Schur's Lemma so I know the ring of endomorphisms is a division ring, I'm not sure how to manipulate this to get the desired result

Comment: Have you tried to exhibit an isomorphism? An endomorphism $\varphi:S^n\to S^n$ can be written as a matrix. Can you see how? Consider first vector spaces, say. This is very similar to what one does in linear algebra.

Comment: No I'm not really sure, as a square nxn matrix? @PedroTamaroff

Answer (score 0):

Prove the following:

For $\phi\in\mathrm{End}_R(S^n)$, define
$$\phi_{ij}=\pi_j\circ\phi\circ \iota_i$$
where $\pi_j:S^n\to S$ is the projection onto the $j$th factor and $\iota_i:S\to S^n$ is the natural embedding into the $i$th factor. Then, the map $$\mathrm{End}_R(S^n)\to M_n(\mathrm{End}_R(S))$$ given by $\phi\mapsto(\phi_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$ is an isomorphism.